# Posting content from Buffer API

Tags: php, api, oauth, get, buffer

I've used this OAuth Library https://github.com/thewebguy/bufferapp-php and am trying to pull my buffer posts into my website.

However, I can't understand how to make the calls correctly and display the content.

I can correctly access the API and it posts the content, but what I am trying to work out is how to display the content from my buffered posts on my website.

I have used the following code to make a post successfully:

```
<?
session_start();
require('buffer.php');

$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$callback_url = 'http://www.readadvisors.com';

$buffer = new BufferApp($client_id, $client_secret, $callback_url);

if (!$buffer->ok) {
    echo '<a href="' . $buffer->get_login_url() . '">Connect to Buffer!</a>';
} else {
    $profiles = $buffer->go('/profiles');

    if (is_array($profiles)) {
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            //$buffer->go('/updates/create', array('text' => 'My first status update from bufferapp-php worked!', 'profile_ids[]' => $profile->id));
            $buffer->go('/profiles/:id/updates/sent');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now I want to be able to use this code for other API calls as seen here: https://buffer.com/developers/api/updates

I am particularly interested in GET /profiles/:id/updates/sent

Many thanks for your help!!!

R

Comment: `:id` is clearly just a token and meant to be replaced by the actual id of the profile you're interested in.  `$buffer->go('/profiles/'.$profile->id.'/updates/sent');` should do the trick.

Comment: Many thanks @PatrickQ, but I now get an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/readadvisors/readadvisors.com/oauth/example.php on line 19 and that line reads: 'print $buffer->go('/profiles/'.$profile->id.'/updates/sent');'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://github.com/miguelbemartin/buffer-sdk-php

and it's really simple to get the sent updates:

```php
// Create a new AuthorizationToken
$auth = new AuthorizationToken('XXX');

// Create a new Buffer Wrapper Client
$buffer = new Buffer($auth);

// Get Profiles
$profiles = $buffer->profileService->getProfiles();

foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
   $updates = $buffer->updateService->getSentUpdates($profile["id"]);
}
```